# Почему на iphone 4s элемент отображается иначе?

Tags: html, css

Почему на iphone after расположен иначе, чем в эмуляторе хрома?

[image: ПК] ПК

[image: Iphone] Iphone

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

.b-tile__text-link--look-collection-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: 70px;
   left: 25px;
   text-align: left;
   line-height: 1.3;
}
.b-tile__text-link--look-collection-link:after {
   content: "";
   background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
   background-position: 0px -53px;
   width: 5px;
   height: 9px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   right: auto;
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->
<span class="b-tile__text-link b-tile__text-link--look-collection-link">Kollektion ansehen</span>
```

Comment: Дела то что каждый браузер со своими параметрами, то что работает в одно может не работать в другом.

Comment: Ни один эмулятор не отобразит ваш код так же, как оригинал интерпретатора кода.